# VPN verbose logging on High Sierra

Tags: vpn, high-sierra

I'm having problems connecting over VPN on certain networks and I'd like to look at the VPN log.

According to https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/mac-help/set-advanced-vpn-options-mh11941 I can set the "Use verbose logging" setting via Network Preferences > VPN > Advanced. However the only options I get under Advanced are the ones for DNS and Proxies; there's nothing specific to VPN in there.

How can I enable VPN verbose logging on High Sierra?

Answer (score 1):

Verbose logging option is only available for an L2TP over IPSEC connection type.  If you selected CISCO IPSEC when configuring your VPN connection in the network preference the Verbose logging option will not be available.